# Retaining scrollbar position using jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have a java function,

```
private GroupsSelector group(LabourInputReportCriteria.Level level) {
            HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox box = new HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox();
            boolean isSelected = selections.isGroupSelected(level);
            box.setSelected(isSelected);
            // box.setDisabled(isDaySelectedOnFirst(level));
            String id="groupBy" + level.getClass().getSimpleName();
            box.setId(id);

            box.setOnclick("submit()");


            box.addValueChangeListener(u.addExpressionValueChangeListener("#{reportSearchCriteriaModel.groupBy}"));
            HtmlOutputText labelComponent = new HtmlOutputText();

            labelComponent.setValue(getGroupSelectionValue(level));
            tr().td();
            html(box);


            html("&nbsp;");

            html(labelComponent);
            //html("<span id='"+id+ "'></span>");

            //html("<script> function resetGroupsSelector() {  var x = document.getElementById('search_report_form:groupByWeekLevel'); alert(x); } </script>");

            endTd().endTr();
            return this;
        }
```

Whenever I click on a checkbox, sumbit() is called and it has some functionality at the backend. Now, my question is whenever I click on a checkbox, the scrollbar position is moving up i.e, it is going on top of the page.  I want to avoid this. I want to retain my scrollbar position as it is. How am I supposed to do it?

I tried adding the follwing code but it dint work.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" >
var addTweet = function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#results9016').prepend($newTweet);
    $('html, body').scrollTop(scrollPosition);
}
</script>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

inside the function that you call when clicking you can say

```
function submit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
}
```

Comment: But my submit() method is in server. Can I modify it?

Comment: Should I do like this? box.setOnclick("submit(event) {event.preventDefault();} ");

Comment: actually the onclick is a js call not a server call (if using the browser). check this [link](http://www.redips.net/javascript/maintain-scroll-position/)

Comment: But the body of sumbit() is in server side.

Comment: sumbit() has some functionality. Hence, if I place {event.preventDefault();} functionality gets affected. And I cannot modify the actual submit().